# How to print values of fields of self-referential C++ class via shared pointer in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have encountered code that looks something like this - I'm not really sure if this is an example of a self-referential class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // std::shared_ptr

namespace internal
{
class SomeThing
{
public:
  int count = 0;
};
}

class SomeThing final
{
public:
  SomeThing();
  ~SomeThing();
  void Process( int innum );
private:
  internal::SomeThing* p;
};

SomeThing::SomeThing()
    : p( new internal::SomeThing() )
{
}

SomeThing::~SomeThing()
{
  delete p;
}

void SomeThing::Process( int innum )
{
  p->count = p->count + innum;
}

static SomeThing something;
static std::shared_ptr<SomeThing> something_ptr{ std::shared_ptr<SomeThing>{}, &something };

int main() {
  something.Process(3);
  // something.p->count: error: 'p' is a private member of 'SomeThing'
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile this and debug in `gdb`, it is easy to print out the `count` field via the `something` variable:

```
$ g++ -g -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp
$ gdb --args ./main
...
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0xbbb: file main.cpp, line 42.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/runner/e3t9ocha14t/main 
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:42
42    something.Process(3);

(gdb) p something
$1 = {p = 0x561b93a98e70}

(gdb) p something->p
$2 = (internal::SomeThing *) 0x561b93a98e70

(gdb) p *something->p
$3 = {count = 0}
```

However, can I do the same (get to, and print the value of the `count` field) via the shared pointer? I cannot really figure out how to do it:

```
(gdb) p something_ptr
$4 = std::shared_ptr<SomeThing> (empty) = {
  get() = 0x561b92e02148 <something>}
(gdb) p something_ptr._M_ptr
$5 = (std::__shared_ptr<SomeThing, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::element_type *) 0x561b92e02148 <something>
```

If this was C, I could have just dereferenced the pointer, i.e. `p *my_ptr` - but what can I do in this case of `shared_ptr` in C++?

Comment: Isn't `p *something_ptr` working?

Comment: Thanks @273K - just checked, and indeed: it prints `{p = 0x561b93a98e70}`  - and I could print `p *something_ptr->p` -- and finally could print `p (*something_ptr->p)->count` correctly! Feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: What `p`? The smart pointer has  `_M_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks @273K - I'm a bit confused now; I entered `p *something_ptr` to print, and as a result I got `$6 = {p = 0x561b93a98e70}`; this tells me that a property `p` is accessible, likely the `internal::SomeThing* p;` - and indeed, it is so, since then I used `p (*something_ptr->p)->count` in gdb, to print the `count` field directly, and it did, and so my question is answered